# I am not able to display the Json data which has fetch through rest api in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have code which fetch the Json data through rest API but not able to display the Json data, I tried to debug the data the code is compiling fine without errors when i try with inspect it seems to be Network error.

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/login/?username=ramya1&password=start1`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({persons:persons});
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { <li>{this.state.persons.name}</li>}
        { <li>{this.state.persons.id}</li>}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

enter code here

Comment: `http://localhost:8080` might be a different origin. You might have to enable [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on your API.

Comment: You should also tell us what the error is, that will help.

Comment: Small nitpick, you can simply use `this.setState({persons});`. It's functionally equivalent to the code you already have.

Comment: Please share the error what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> >   componentDidMount()  works when page is loaded, you need to use click event for passing username ans password
> ```

```
    import React from 'react';

    import axios from 'axios';

    export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
      state = {
        persons: [],
        username: '',
        password: ''
      }

      function ActionLink() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }

      render() {
        return (
    <div><form>
    <label>
                            <span class="text">user:</span>
                            <input type="email" id="email"/><br/>
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <label>
                            <span class="text">password:</span>
                            <input type="password" id="password"/><br/>
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="align-right">
                            <button onclick={this.click_event}>Submit</button>
    </form>
          <ul>
            { <li>{this.state.persons.name}</li>}
            { <li>{this.state.persons.id}</li>}
          </ul>
    </div>
        )
      }
    }
```